# Listen to html5 autofocus

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html form that I want it to be autofocused when a user loads a page.
`<form>
<input type=text name='username' id='input1' autofocus>`

I have Javascript that is meant to add a **css class(** *shift-up* **)**  to the input to style it when the input is in focus.

```
`var x=document[forms][input1]; 
x.addEventListener('focus', inputFocus); 
function inputFocus {
x.classList.add('shift-up');
} `
```

My **problems:**

This class is not added to the input tag when a user loads the page and yet the input field is focused. But when you click manually, then the class is added.

Is there any way I could also listen to the html5 autofocus using Javascript??

Comment: Assuming the need for the `shift-up` class is visual, could you use CSS with the `:focus` psuedoclass?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `:focus` selector in your CSS instead.  No need for JavaScript add/remove classes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of taking use of "difficult" **JavaScript code** to get your `<input>` work. Make use of the `:focus` option in **CSS**, which already exists and is way simpler than try to code your own focus with an `EventListener`.

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type=text name='username' class="placeholder">
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.placeholder:focus{

}
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved by adding some explanation, in this case explaining why you think that putting the code for shift-up into the CSS you've shown is a better solution than using JavaScript.

Comment: You are right I was in hurry and just wanted to help him.